# ASP.NET API Post method not working after publishing on the host

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, api

I'm trying to call my API using POST method, and it suppose to return (Status = "True") in JSON format.

THe API works fine when I'm call it from my device, but when I publish it to the host it always return a message says: (No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI).

My Code is:

Model:

```
public class CbActions
{
    public string Status { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Controller

```
    [Route("api/CBController/CbSts")]
    [HttpGet, HttpPost]
    public List<CbActions> CBStatus(Data d)
    {
        if (d != null)
        {
            string Id = d.ID;
            string date = d.Date;
            string name = d.Name;
        }
        

        List<CbActions> output = new List<CbActions>();

        
        output.Add(new CbActions { Status = "True"});

        return output;
    }
```

Web.config:

```
<system.web>
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet" />
    <add name="HttpPost" />
  </protocols>
</webServices> 
</system.web>
```

Also:

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

</system.webServer>

I called my API from my device like this:
**http://localhost/CBAPI/api/CBController/CbSts**

Also I calling it from the Host in the same way:
**https://xxxx.com/CBAPI/api/CBController/CbSts**

Could you please tell me what I'm missing or Where I did a mistake ???

Thanks

Comment: @Selvin sorry, thats my mistake. What I meant that I call it in the same way on the host but not localhost.. I replace localhost with the domain name but it still returns the same message

Comment: Where `CBAP` does come from? When you define `[Route("api/CBController/CbSts")]` you should be able to call it as `http://localhost/api/CBController/CbSts` not `http://localhost/CBAPI/api/CBController/CbSts`

Comment: @SelimYildiz If you mean **CBAPI**, It's the project name. It's the folder where all project files located.

Comment: @SelimYildiz I call it from the host like this: `https://xxxx/api/CBController/CbSts`
without **CBAPI**. But it returns the same message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies with decorating your action method with `[HttpGet, HttpPost]`.

An action should only ever have a single verb attribute applied.

In the rare case your action does need to accept multiple verbs then you should use:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get | HttpVerbs.Post)]
```

However I'd suggest you create a separate action method for each.

Comment: Thanks You It worked, as you said I think I need to seperate actions for better performence and cleared code.